# How to extend heroku-buildpack-core-data with a complete web frontend

Tags: api, core-data, heroku

I'm impressed with the Heroku recently added heroku-buildpack-core-data by @mattt (more info [here](http://mobile.heroku.com/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20hnycombinator%20%28HN%20-%20hnycombinator%29)) that helps a lot in building a web API for core-data backed iOS Apps. I would like to extend it to have also a web front-end. I see that it has a Sinatra+Sequel app inside.

Which is the heroku-friendly way to add this?
Do I have to fork and extend the buildpack?

Answer (score 1):

You can find instructions on how to extend this functionality with Rack::CoreData on the [Core Data Buildpack Repository](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-core-data):

> **The Core Data Buildpack is designed to encourage rapid prototyping, but should not be used on its own in production applications.**
>
> Rather, you are encouraged to create an application using Rack::CoreData directly, which allows you to extend the Core Data scaffolding with Rack applications, such as Rails or Sinatra, and middleware. Here's an example config.ru file:

#### config.ru

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])

run Rack::CoreData('./Example.xcdatamodeld')
```